# Operar entre dos columnas definidas por un alias

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo dos columnas; una con el salario de cada empleado llamada **Salary** y otra con ese mismo salario pero incrementado en un 15%. Esta ultima columna tiene como alias **New Salary**. Me piden que reste la columna de Salary a la de New Salary y que la nombre como **Increase**.

El caso está en que no se como hacer referencia a la columna de "New Salary" para hacer la resta. Si hago *(Salary - New Salary) as "Increase"* obviamente no funcionará ya que estoy utilizando el alias

Como puedo hacer referencia a la columna de **New Salary** en una consulta para hacer la resta?

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que yo he intentado hacer es:

```
Select 
 employee_id, 
 last_name, 
 salary, 
 trunc(salary+(salary*0.15)) as "New Salary", 
 salary-New Salary as "Increase"
From employees;
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado, pon además la estructura de tus tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
 T.employed_id,
 T.last_name,
 T.salary,
 T.NewSalary,
 T.NewSalary - T.salary as Incremento
From
(
 Select 
 employee_id, 
 last_name, 
 salary, 
 trunc(salary * 1.15) as NewSalary
 From employees
) T;
```

Sobre tu consulta original haces otra consulta dónde puedes hacer la resta que deseas, por otra parte basta multiplicar **salary * 1.15** para obtener el aumento del **15%**.